# Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem recurse depth only for first two folders

Tags: azure, powershell

```
$ChildItem = Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $ctx -FileSystem 
$Container.Name  -MaxCount $MaxReturn  -ContinuationToken $Token

Foreach ($Item in $ChildItem){

   $Token = $Item[$item.Count -1].ContinuationToken

   Write-Host "File: $($Container.Name)"/"$($Item.Path)”
}
```

I tried removing the -Recurse parameter but I only get the first folder back

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end I could able to achieve your requirement using `Where-Object`. Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
$ListOfFiles = Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Recurse -FetchProperty

$ListOfFiles | Where-Object { $_.Path -match "dir1/" -or $_.Path -match "dir2/"}
```

Results:

[image]